# CaptchaMvc using Ajax.beginform asp.net mvc4

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, captcha

Im using CaptchaMvc.Mvc4 1.5.0 in my asp.net mvc4 application.
this is my view:

```
@using CaptchaMvc.HtmlHelpers;
@using CaptchaMvc;
@model Web.Models.Message
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Contact", "Home", new AjaxOptions
{
    HttpMethod = "post",
    InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
    UpdateTargetId = "Sent"
}
{
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>                       
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name)
            <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
            </div>  
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Email)
            <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Email)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Email)
            </div>                              
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Message1)
            <div>
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Message1)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Message1)
            </div>

            @Html.MathCaptcha()

            <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </fieldset>

            <div id="Sent">
            </div>
  }
```

and this is my Action Method :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Contact(Message message)
{
   if(this.IsCaptchaValid("error"))           
   if (ModelState.IsValid )
   {
       db.Messages.Add(message);
       db.SaveChanges();
       return RedirectToAction("SuccessfullySent");
    }

    ModelState.AddModelError("", "there is some error");
    return View(message);
}
```

it works fine when captcha input is valid.
problem is when captcha is invalid , the whole view is rendered in the div with id="Sent" . So i have two Message View rendered in one page. 
How can i prevent it to render the whole view again in the div with id="Sent"?

Answer (score 0):

You are returning the same `View` which you use to initially render the page.

This means that the updated div is being replaced by the entire page.

You could just return the message as follows:

```
return Content("there is some error");
```

Which would output the message to the sent div.

Alternatively you could return a `PartialView` if it contained more Html and pass the message in as follows:

```
return PartialView("_errorPartial", "there is some error");
```

Comment: tnx mate it worked. but now there is another problem. after returning  return Content("there is some error"); page disposes , and i cant re submit  the message.